# Как узнать пароль к БД Firebird

Tags: firebird

Добрый день. Имеется копия бд `Firebird`(для тестирования), оригинал располагается локально. В общем то разницы между ними нету, только для тестирования. Мне нужно сделать коннект, но выдает ошибку, а именно :

```
     "Error while connecting to database:")
    fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- 
    SQLCODE: -902\n- Unable to complete network request to host 
    "localhost".\n- Failed to establish a connection.', -902, 335544721)
```

Данная ошибка свидетельствует о том, что неверные данные для входа. Суть вот в чем, могу ли я как-то узнать его? Имею доступ к компьютеру, на котором располагается оригинал, основная ОС - Windows.
Может можно его перехватить, или поискать в папке программы какие-либо конфиги(БД лежит в ней)

Comment: *Данная ошибка свидетельствует о том, что неверные данные для входа.* -- откуда такая информация? Само сообщение об ошибке говорит совсем о другом.

Comment: @D-side (http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=gdscodes).
ошибка -902 говорит что неправильные логин и пароль.
Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up an InterBase login.

Comment: К -902 там безумное количество возможных ошибок.

Comment: @D-side (http://joxi.ru/Rmz5eE3fWwQ0yr) вот еще

Comment: Там нет ничего, чего нет в вопросе.

Comment: @D-side ой, ошибочка. Ссылка действительно не та ( недосып)
Тогда о чем она говорит? 
В любом случае я не знаю пароль к БД и мне надо его как-то найти

Comment: По сообщению похоже, что он не может установить сетевое соединение с сервером Firebird. Что до входа под аккаунтом и дело-то не дошло, он сервер СУБД не нашел по указанному адресу.